# Can I extend int.TryParse method?

Tags: c#, parsing

### I wish I had the following method

```
int num;  
int.TryParse("5",out num, 10);
```

Which will do the same as TryParse, but addtional if the parsing fails,
the out parameter will get the defualt value 10

Can I implement it?

With extension methods I can implement the following:

```
int num;
num.TryParse("5",out num, 10);
```

But this look different than the rest of the TryParse methods..

Comment: Checkout this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078512/why-does-integer-tryparse-set-result-to-zero-on-failure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot add static methods to existing classes, but you can add your own static method to your own class, for example:

```
public static class MyConversions
{
   public static bool TryParse(string value, out int num, int defaultValue)
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A one-liner without writing a helper method would be:

```
int num = int.TryParse("5", out num) ? num : 10;
```

And here is a string-extension method: http://neue.cc/2010/04/09_251.html

Answer (score 2):

You could create an extension method for string:

```
int num;
"5".TryParse(out num, 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to implement static extension method. Look at this question: [Static extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866921/static-extension-methods)
Ways to go:
a. Implement extension method on strings not ints:

```
public static int Parse(this string s, int defaultValue) {
   int result;
   return Int32.TryParse(s,out result) ? result : defaultValue;
}
...
int num = "5".Parse(10); //
```

b. Implement your own IntUtil class with TryParse(string, out int, int) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create static extension methods, so you can't do what you want unfortunately.

If you really didn't like what you've got so far (non-static method) then you could create your own class with that static method as per @Jamiec's answer.

Answer (score 1):

TryParse returns an boolean to say if the parsing worked or not. So:

```
int num;
if (!num.TryParse("5", out num))
{
    num = 10;
}
```

You can't use that as an extension method, but you can still leave it somewhere appropriate as a static method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't extend `TryParse`. Both because it is a static method and because `Int32` is a struct can can't be inherited from.

You can write your own [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) though.