# Elegant TryParse

Tags: c#

I feel that every time I use `TryParse` that it results in somewhat ugly code. Mainly I am using it this way:

```
int value;
if (!int.TryParse(someStringValue, out value))
{
    value = 0;
}
```

Is there some more elegant solution for parsing all basic data types, to be specific is there a way to do fail safe parsing in one line? By fail safe I assume setting default value if parsing fails without exception.

By the way, this is for cases where I must do some action even if parsing fails, just using the default value.

Comment: The default for int is 0 and is used with an out-parameter, but anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1078521/284240

Comment: @Tim sometimes it's not type default value, not talking specifically for int, but other data types

Comment: @AntonioBakula: Then use Jon Skeets approach in my link and use ref parameter in your own `TryParse`.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

This is valid and you may prefer it if you have a liking for single-liners:

```
int i = int.TryParse(s, out i) ? i : 42;
```

This sets the value of `i` to `42` if it cannot parse the string `s`, otherwise it sets `i = i`.

Comment: +1 I must admit that i didn't know that it works in one line. I could have sworn that at least VB.NET doesnt like it, but: `Dim i As Int32 = If(Int32.TryParse("nonum", i), i, 42)`. Thanks.

Comment: I like this answer so much!

Comment: In case you directly want to return the result: `return int.TryParse(s, out int i) ? i : 42;`

Comment: It's a little redundant, though. You only want to perform an additional assignment when `TryParse` returns false, but the tertiary operator requires you to account for both cases.

Comment: Note that the updated version from @BalintPogatsa requries C# 7.0

Comment: I think it should be: int i = (int.TryParse(s, out i)) ? i : 42;

Answer (score 24):

how about a direct extension method?

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int? TryParse(this string Source)
    {
        int result;
        if (int.TryParse(Source, out result))
            return result;
        else

            return null;
    }
}
```

or with the new c# syntax in a single line:

```
public static int? TryParse(this string Source) => int.TryParse(Source, out int result) ? result : (int?)null;
```

usage:

```
v = "234".TryParse() ?? 0
```

Comment: I like this more than @skarmats answer, even though probably it's a matter of personal preference

Comment: @AntonioBakula: Yes, preference always matters. However, you won't get type inference on return values. So you will pollute the String-IntelliSense with lots of methods (one for each type you want to parse)

Comment: Example implementation here: https://ericlippert.com/2012/08/14/out-parameters-and-linq-do-not-mix/ :  static int? MyTryParse(this string item) {
  int tmp;
  bool success = int.TryParse(item, out tmp);
  return success ? (int?)tmp : (int?)null; 
}

Comment: To save you some typing, here the extension class for most common primitives: https://hastebin.com/eleyawonex.cs

Answer (score 15):

You can write your own methods for a solution that suits you better. I stumbled upon the `Maybe` class that wraps the `TryParse` methods a while ago.

```
int? value = Maybe.ToInt("123");

if (value == null)
{
    // not a number
}
else
{
    // use value.Value
}
```

or specify the default value in-line:

```
int value = Maybe.ToInt("123") ?? 0;
```

Observe the distinction between `Nullable<int>`/`int?` and `int`.

See http://www.kodefuguru.com/post/2010/06/24/TryParse-vs-Convert.aspx for more info

Comment: Please provide a link to the Maybe class you mention

Comment: The link in the answer is 404

Comment: FYI, there's a good implementation of Maybe in a micro library here:  https://github.com/vkhorikov/CSharpFunctionalExtensions

Comment: The original page is cached on https://web.archive.org/web/20100630161315/http://www.kodefuguru.com/post/2010/06/24/TryParse-vs-Convert.aspx. The code of the Maybe class from from KodefuGuru can be found on GitHub as well: https://github.com/kodefuguru/kodefu/blob/master/Kodefu/Maybe.cs

Answer (score 13):

There is a nice little feature in <s>C# 6</s> C# 7, [Declaration expressions](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Documentation), so in C# 7 instead of:

```
int x;
if (int.TryParse("123", out x))
{
  DoSomethingWithX(x);
}
```

we can use:

```
if (int.TryParse("123", out int x))
{
  DoSomethingWithX(x);
}
```

Nice enough for me :)

Comment: Unfortunately declaration expressions didn't make the final cut for C# 6.

Comment: @dav_i But we have it now in C# 7! Hallelujah!

Comment: @EricSondergard It truly has been a rollercoaster of emotion.

Comment: This is nice, but it's still missing the default value. Here we are just avoiding the declaration line.

Answer (score 5):

using C# 7 in single line

```
int.TryParse(s, out var i) ? i : (int?)null;
```

Example Method:

```
public static int? TryParseSafe(string s)
{
    return int.TryParse(s, out var i) ? i : (int?)null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your particular example, you can do this:

```
int value; 
int.TryParse(someStringValue, out value);
```

...because Int32.TryParse() is documented as setting `value=0` if it fails the parse.

Comment: same as comment to Tim: sometimes it's not type default value, not talking specifically for int, but other data types

Answer (score 1):

You could use TypeDescriptor instead:

```
public T Convert<T>(string input, T defaultVal)
{
    var converter = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
    if(converter != null)
    {
        return (T)converter.ConvertFromString(input);
    }
    return defaultVal;
}

public T Convert<T>(string input)
{
    return Convert(input, default(T));
}
```

You could constrain `T` to struct and use `Nullable` also (as per @skarmats answer).

Comment: You could always use an optional parameter in this case so your first signature reads `Convert<T>(string input, T defaultVal = default(T))` and the second method can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I have small enhancement for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10693302/9436994), which is making an extension method and TryConvert extension method in snippet below:

```
public static T Convert<T>(this string input, T defaultVal)
{
    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
    if (converter != null)
    {
        return (T) converter.ConvertFromString(input);
    }
    return defaultVal;
}

public static T Convert<T>(this string input)
{
    return Convert(input, default(T));
}

public static bool TryConvert<T>(this string input, T defaultVal, out T result)
{
    try
    {
        result = Convert(input, defaultVal);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        result = defaultVal;
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input);
    }
}
```

And then we can use it this like a snippet

```
 if (someValue.TryConvert(1, out var result))
 {

 }
```

The `result` data type is automatically depending on defaultVal

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the nice surprises for C# developers who try F#. 
The TryParse method returns a tuple containing both the bool and the value.