# Tidying up if statements

Tags: c#, if-statement, operators

I made a little program that works out physics calculations using math.

I have couple of `if` statements that do same thing but to different variables, but it must be them as if a `TextBox` is empty, the `int` will be `0`.

Here's the example:

```
if (firstForceTextBox.Text == "")
{
    firstForceInt = 0;
}
else
{
    firstForceInt = Convert.ToInt16(firstForceTextBox.Text);
}

if (secondForceTextBox.Text == "")
{
    secondForceInt = 0;
}
else
{
    secondForceInt = Convert.ToInt16(secondForceTextBox.Text);
}
```

I want to make sure that both `firstForceTextBox.Text == ""` and `secondForceTextBox.Text == ""` do the same job but make sure that one doesn't intervene with other.

Comment: You could default `firstForceInt` and `secondForceInt` to be zero at the start, and use `int.TryParse` when you check the textbox-values.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  I see a few different ways you could _shorten_ the code, but there's nothing _wrong_ with what you have now.

Comment: What intervention are you worried about? They don't use any of the same variables. It could easily be *shorter* code, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: I'm trying to shorten down and tidy up the code, where if one text box is empty, THAT specific textbox int is set 0 while others are what they are.

Comment: As @NoLifeKing mention, I wish to default the values of these variables, so it does not kick an error when calculating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
firstForceInt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstForceTextBox.Text) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt16(firstForceTextBox.Text);
secondForceInt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(secondForceTextBox.Text) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt16(secondForceTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you very much! (Going to choose this as an answer)

Answer (score 7):

To clarify what I'm doing here.

First I set a default value for the two `int` stated.

Then I use `int.TryParse` to ensure that the code doesn't break if you put "banana" into the textbox.
If it fails, it will just contain 0, like it should.

```
int firstForceInt = 0, secondForceInt = 0;
if(!int.TryParse(firstForceTextBox.Text, out firstForceInt))
{
    // Report error to GUI
}
if(!int.TryParse(secondForceTextBox.Text, out secondForceInt))
{
    // Report error to GUI
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this changes the behavior such that values which do not represent valid integers silently evaluate to zero, whereas the OP's code would throw an exception.  However, if this is the desired behavior, then your answer is best.  Also, since `out` parameters are definitely assigned, the variable initializers are redundant.

Comment: It wasn't stated that we should report any errors, but since it's physics, I should've thought of that. I'll make an edit.

Comment: @NoLifeKing I didn't read every detail in the question - my comment was more from a good practice standpoint. I removed my previous comment after your edit.

Comment: Yep this works well too...I wish I could vote up but I'm still too low :D

Answer (score 2):

I would apply a refactoring technique called extract method to obtain someting like so

```
private UInt16 GetInt16(TextBox textBox)
{
    if (textBox.Text == "")
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return Convert.ToInt16(textBox.Text);
    }

private void Later() 
{
    firstForceInt = GetInt16(firstForceTextBox);
    secondForceInt = GetInt16(secondForceTextBox);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can take my function from here:
[Elegant TryParse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693231/elegant-tryparse/10693310#10693310)

and extend it:

```
public class Extensions
{
public static int? TryParse(string this Source)
{
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Source)) return null;
if(int.tryparse .... 
}

}
```

later you can write

```
firstForceInt = firstForceTextBox.Text.TryParse() ?? 0;
```

Comment: In general, I do not recommend writing these kinds of extension methods, but if you're going to write them, I'd at least recommend including the result type in the method name.  That clarifies the method's purpose, e.g., it parses integers and not haikus, so call it `TryParseInt32`.  This scheme also provides for greater consistency if you add similar methods for other types in the future, e.g., `TryParseDouble`.