# TryParse places 0 on the variable when parse fails

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, try-catch, tryparse

Take this code snippet.

```
string input = "";
int value = 10;
bool success = int.TryParse(input, out value);
```

Whatever I use in `input`, be it `null`, `""`, `"a"`, etc, when it's not a valid number, it returns `false` and paces 0 into `value`.

Isn't `TryParse()` meant to return a bool informing about sucess on the parse? When parse fails, shouldn't it just leave the variable unchanged?

This is annoying. So I'll need a variable to hold the value before calling `TryParse()`, and make a `if` to verify its result, and in case of failure copy the previous value back into the variable?

Update. I didn't find this behavior described in [official doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), can you point where Microsoft describes it?

I mean, parsing in general, and `TryParse()`specially, isn't meant just to parse a string. It's also meant to validate the string. If `TryParse()` fails and returns `false`, it's not an error or exception, it means the string isn't a valid int (or whatever the data type), so I must handle this invalid string. That probably requires the previous value of the variable. If the variable is set to 0, the previous value is lost.

Why place a junk value and lose the previous value? This way, as I said, I'd need a second variable to hold that value, it's a waste.

I can extend or wrap `TryParse()`, but I'll need to do that to all data types.

Comment: It can't not set it - it's an `out` parameter.  If you need the functionality you desire, it wouldn't be hard to wrap it up in another method that takes a `ref` param instead.

Comment: It seems to me that it's behaving exactly as it's documented to: "When this method returns, contains the 32-bit signed integer value equivalent of the number contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, or zero if the conversion failed."

Comment: Read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078512/why-does-integer-tryparse-set-result-to-zero-on-failure

Comment: Regarding your edit/update - the section quoted by @JonSkeet is in the _Parameters_ section under _result_

Comment: Also you haven't lost the value you were trying to parse, that's still in `input`.  If you want to set a default value to `value`, do `int value; if (!int.TryParse(input, out value)) { value = 10 };` ie rather than setting it before, set it after it's failed.

Comment: Thanks for the quote. @James it's not the string input that I mean it's lost, it's the int value that's replaced by 0 when the parse fails. If the int variable was just created then it's no issue, but if it had a meaningful value that's replaced by a default 0 value then it's an issue. Anyway, I got it, gonna handle it properly when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) will Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation succeeded; so what we can do is:

```
if(int.TryParse(input, out value))
{
 // proceed with your code
} 
else 
{
 // show some message that the input is not valid
}
```